# Cómo se renueva un JWToken en el backend?

Tags: java

En mi Backend tengo un interceptor Http, en el cual hago las validaciones, como por ejemplo si el token está expirado. Ahora quiero que se renueve el tiempo cada vez que pasa por ese interceptor y el token no está vencido, cómo debería hacerlo?

Comment: bienvenido a stackoverflow, te invito a pasar por el [tour| y de paso leer [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Los tokens no pueden modificarse tal como comentas.

Los JWT no son otra cosa que una serie de datos y metadatos cifrados (explicación MUY resumida). Esto implica que si modificas alguno de los datos o metadatos con los que generaste un token X e intentas generar otro Y verás que ambos son diferentes.

Lo anterior implica que si quisieras que cada vez que un usuario use su token se aumente su tiempo de expiración tendrías que generar uno nuevo y enviárselo de vuelta.

Mi recomendación (y el modo en que lo hago yo en mi empresa) es que sean las aplicaciones clientes quienes manejen el tema de la expiración del token y le pidan al usuario que ingrese sus credenciales con el objetivo de generar uno nuevo. Claro está, tienes que implementar un mecanismo en el backend que cuando detecte que este ha expirado envíe al cliente un código de error que le permita saber de este hecho.